# How to get the latest dates with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

I have this Common Table Expression which should pull data for clients who have received services 'S' after '2015-07-01' and latest enrollment 'e' date should be before '2015-07-01’ but the result set includes clients who have been re-enrolled after '2015-07-01’ because they also have multiple enrollment like services. Not sure what clause to include to make sure their LATEST enrollment begin date is before '2015-07-01’.

```
WITH PhoneLog AS
(
select s.ProvidedToEntityID, 
concat (c.FirstName,' ', C.LastName) as ClientName,
ecp.CellPhone, 
 ecp.HomePhone, 
 case ecp.PhoneVoiceOptIn
when 1 then 'Yes'
when 2 then 'No'
Else 'Unknown'
End as ContactViaPhone,
  S.BeginDate ServiceStart, 
 e.BeginDate  EnrollmentBeginDate,
case 
when Dateadd(YY,Datediff(YY,c.birthdate,getdate()), c.birthdate)> getdate()
then datediff(YY,birthdate,getdate())
else datediff(YY,birthdate,getdate())
end as 'Current Age',
e.X_ProgramStatus as 'program Status',
ROW_NUMBER () over (Partition by s.providedtoEntityID order By s.begindate Desc ) as ClientCount 
  from 
Client c
Join Service s on c.EntityID = s.ProvidedByEntityID
join servicetype st on s.ServiceTypeID = st.ServiceTypeID
join Enrollmentmember Em on c.EntityID = em.ClientID
join enrollment e on em.EnrollmentID = e.EnrollmentID
join Entitycontactpreference ecp on c.entityid = ecp.entityid
where s.BeginDate >= '2015-07-01'
and e.BeginDate < '2015-07-01'
--and s.BeginDate>e.BeginDate
and ecp.PhoneVoiceOptIn = 1
)
SELECT
ProvidedToEntityID,
ClientName,
[Current Age],
cellphone,
Homephone,
ContactViaPhone,
ServiceStart,
EnrollmentBeginDate,
ClientCount,
[program Status]

FROM
    PhoneLog
WHERE
    ClientCount = 1
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are using a CTE. It doesn't seem like it is adding anything for you. I would recommend adding some type of ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY Client ID ORDER BY ENTROLLMENT DESC) RNK ... then filter to only RNK1 to get latest.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

replacing `and e.BeginDate < '2015-07-01'` with

```
-- ...
and e.BeginDate = (select max(e_i.BeginDate)
                   from enrollment e_i
                   where e_i.BeginDate < '2015-07-01')
-- ...
```

Comment: Thanks much worked so I used < instead of =.  Bless you!